# How to post the whole Array of URLs to twitter?

Tags: scala, twitter, playframework

I'm new to Scala and my task is to make a Twitter bot that posts URLs to twitter. I have made a `List` that is called `pickedToTwitter` and contains my URLs.
I need to make a loop that will go through my `List` and make tweets of URLs. Regular `for` and `while` are not working for me. (I need to post one URL at a time).

Here is the code:

```
def send = Action.async { request => 


val data = Map( 
"status" -> "asf" 
) 
val rt: RequestToken = new RequestToken(request.session.get("token").get, request.session.get("secret").get) 

ws.url("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json?stat.." + tweets.pickedToTwitter(0).url).sign(OAuthCalculator(KEY, rt)).post("ignored").map(response => { 
Ok(views.html.main("asd")(Html(response.body))) 
//Redirect(response.body) 
}) 

}
```

Comment: Supposing your list has 5 items, you will make 5 calls to twitter api and get 5 http results. What do you plan to do with those results? You want a result page like "Sent those 5 urls: ..." or it's a "fire and forget" task (you dont care with the results)?

Comment: @Salem I would like the result page "URLs have been sent" and that's it. But as i mentioned before i don't know how can I send those URLs one by one to twitter case the number of URLs is not static and the size of the `List` is different every time.

Answer (score 0):

I can't try it right now, but if I understand correctly, something like this would work:

```
val posts = tweets.pickedToTwitter.map(tweet => ws.url(s"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json?stat${tweet.url}")
    .sign(OAuthCalculator(KEY, rt))
    .post("ignored"))

Future.sequence(posts).map(/* do something with the Future[List[]] */)
```

Though I usually prefer `foreach` to `map` for side effects.